# Simplifying product of differences

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do we simplify this?  Confused.
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why didn't you even try for small numbers? If you had, you could have canceled out all the terms. ;)

The expression turns out to be

$\dfrac{2}{3}.\dfrac{3}{4}.\dfrac{4}{5} \dots\dfrac{n-2}{n-1}.\dfrac{n-1}{n}$

Cancel out the terms and you're left with just $\frac{2}{n}$.

Comment: Wait, small numbers?

Comment: Yeah! Till $5$ or $6$ maybe?. You get $2/5$ for $n=5$ and $2/6$ for $n=6$. ;)

Comment: you know $\frac{2}{3}<\frac{3}{4}<\cdots$ right?